# Sending notification within app actions

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I would like to send a notification to selected devices once the action has been completed. For example: once user hit the submit button, it will send a notification to alert the selected users.

So far what i seen is to use google cloud messenger but that needs a server which needs to be typed by a human which is not i want.

Any advise?

Thanks.

Comment: I think use can use [this](https://github.com/google/gcm/tree/master/samples/android/gcm-demo) on `notification` tag, it can send notification from one client(mobile) to another without other server. You need to use `GcmServerSideSender` on this.

Comment: Currently GCM requires a third party server (typed by a human :)